# One to many mapping with a ChainMap Dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, one-to-many

I would like do a one to many mapping with the following list and mapping dictonary:

```
l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
l2 = ['a', 'c', 'd']
l3 = ['d', 'e', 'f']


mapping_dict = ChainMap(
        dict.fromkeys(l1, 'A'),
        dict.fromkeys(l2, 'B'),
        dict.fromkeys(l3, 'C'))
```

This is my dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'code': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], 'value': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]})
print(df)

  code  value
0    a      1
1    b      2
2    c      3
3    d      4
4    e      5
5    f      6
```

When I do the mapping as follows:

```
df['mapping'] = df['code'].map(mapping_dict.get)

  code  value mapping
0    a      1       A
1    b      2       A
2    c      3       A
3    d      4       B
4    e      5       C
5    f      6       C
```

The problem is that I want to do a one to many mapping and I don't capture the relationship. The desired outcome would be something like this. Which creates a new line when there are multiple relationships.

```
  code  value mapping
0    a      1       A
1    a      1       B
2    b      2       A
3    c      3       A
4    c      3       B
5    d      4       B
6    d      4       C
7    e      5       C
8    e      5       C
9    f      6       C
```

Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here `ChainMap` can't be used since it will not preserve all the duplicate keys. The solution is to create an intermediate dataframe from each pairs of (mapping, code) and then left `merge` that with the original dataframe

```
pairs = [('A', l1), ('B', l2), ('C', l3)]
mapping = pd.DataFrame(pairs, columns=['mapping', 'code'])

df.merge(mapping.explode('code'), how='left')
```

Result

```
  code  value mapping
0    a      1       A
1    a      1       B
2    b      2       A
3    c      3       A
4    c      3       B
5    d      4       B
6    d      4       C
7    e      5       C
8    f      6       C
```